# Nlog not creating file relative to website project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, nlog

I am using a website project, I added Nlog from Nuget, and used the following NLog configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog autoReload="true" 
      throwExceptions="true" 
      xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="log.txt" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I ran ProcessMonitor and it shows that Nlog is trying to create log.txt in the IISExpress folder instead of my website project folder.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\log.txt

How can I make NLog put my log file, `log.txt`, in my website project's folder instead of the IISExpress folder?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

We figured it out.

Add `${basedir}` to the filename

```
filename="${basedir}/log.txt"
```

Comment: Incidentally, this shouldn't be needed any more; as of version 4.3 relative paths should be computed as relative to `${basedir}`. Tempus fugit.

Comment: and in a desktop application, if you omit some "..\" at the start (i.e. "Logs\mylog.log" rather than "..\Logs\mylog.log"), it'll end up in C:\Users\username\AppData\local\ *sigh*